# Kentico 9 MVC - GetFile.aspx performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico

We have noticed that document attachments (images) that are fetched via the api using /CMSPages/GetFile.aspx are slow to load on our separate MVC application.  I am looking for ways to improve performance for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to answer given the information you provided. What do you mean by slow? How large are the files?

My point of interests would be:

1) Is there a difference in loading times if the file/image is loaded on Kentico app and your MVC site? If yes, then the connection itself could be the problem. If not - how large are the files? Is there any traffic on the site? What about CPU usage?

2) Do you have caching for files enabled? Particularry it's the **Cache files (minutes)** setting under System -> Performance. This can definitely increase the performance since it will be cached on the server side of application.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I think the main issue is that we are loading many images using the same getfile handler / aspx page.  Since these images are more or less static, it makes more sense for us to use the media library instead of page attachments.  Media files provide a file path url (e.g. ~/files/image.jpg) - which can thus be cached by IIS.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, I would actually recommend to use Media library along with a direct path whenever you want to ensure the best possible performance. When you use the handler like GetFile, GetAttachment etc. Kentico always needs to query the DB first to get the proper file. If the file itself is stored in DB, its even worse..